# Text classification with Scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing text classification for two labels with scikit learn .. I am loading my text files with the method load_files

```
categories={'label0','label1'}
text_data = load_files(path,categories=categories)
```

from the following structure:

```
train
├── Label0
│   ├── 0001.txt
│   └── 0002.txt
└── Label1
    ├── 0001.txt
    └── 0002.txt
```

my problem is that when I try to look at the shape of text_data.data it returns:

```
print (type(text_data.data))
<type 'list'>

print text_data.data.shape
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

X = np.array(text_data.data)
print x.shape
(35,)
```

it returns 1D array .. I thought it should be 2D numpy array or a dictionary where the first will be for the text and the other one will be for the class (label0 or 1 ) .. 
have I missed something ?

Comment: I've edited the question .. my problem is that the returned list is a one dimensional array ... only text is stored there ... shouldn't the returned list contain the text as well as the class label ?

Comment: once you get your data in, don't forget to shuffle it and also to create your validation set.  (to be as strict as possible, you should shuffle and split prior to creating your text features (as per David Maust's suggestion))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is after calling load_files, it is not yet a numpy array. It is just a list of text. You should vectorize this text using `CountVectorizer` or `TfidfVectorizer`.

**Example:**

```
cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(text_data.data)
y = text_data.target
print cv.vocabulary_  # Show words in vocabulary with column index

clf = LogisticRegression() # or other classifier
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: thank you .. but how the text linked to the label ? is it by the indexes of both lists (text_data.data and text_data.target) ? also  how can I access the created Sparse matrix as I want to see how it has been constructed .. and can I access the matrix when the CountVectorizer is a apart of a pipeline ?

Comment: yes, exactly. the row index of `X` will correspond to the index of `text_data.target`

Comment: Updated my example to show how to use the sparse matrix. to view it directly, you might try `X[:5,:].todense()` to see the top 5 rows as a dense matrix. You can use `CountVectorizer` in a pipeline, but then the results will immediately be given to the next step.